# Options for miniature/tile storage at home

Tags: miniatures

I am looking for options to store miniatures and dungeon tiles for my apartment.  We play here so ability to transport is not an issue.  I currently live in an apartment so I don't have room for large shelves or mounting or anything.  My miniatures are also 3D printed so they are stiffer and will break more then they will bend.

I'm looking for cheaper solutions but willing to spend a little more if it's worth it.  Most of the options are carrying cases but I don't need that as I play at my place.

Comment: Can you edit your question and be more specific? What are you looking for? Low-cost solutions? Low-price?

Answer (score 0):

In my house, we use something like this (although smaller):

[image]

Ours is 40×40cm, with each division being about 5×5cm, and about 10cm depth.

We don't have much room on the walls either, so we keep it horizontal under the bed, with all the miniatures separated by campaign, player, use, etc. On game nights, we take it to the living room and take minis from there. You can also keep other useful things, like pencils, dice, etc, on each division.

It is usually not very expensive to get something like this in your common 99-cent store.

Comment: How big is that?  Looks like it could be a china cabinet.

Comment: Edited with dimensions. This isn't the actual picture of our cabinet, but I'm not home right now, I'll edit it on the weekend

Comment: that's just wanted to get an idea of how big it is.